# Call ambiguous function in gdb with stripped symbols

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to call a function with

```
(gdb) call fun()
```

in a 3rd party library `libFoo` which I get in compiled form with stripped symbols.

```
(gdb) info function ^fun$
Non-debugging symbols:
0x00007ffff6d7e3b0  fun
```

Problem is, there is an unrelated system library `libBar` loaded which also has `fun` in it, a variable this time, and gdb prefers that symbol instead of the desired one. I suspect that this is because this hit is a non-stripped debugging symbol.

```
(gdb) info var ^fun$
File ../bar/baz.c:
256:    static const int fun[18];

(gdb) info symbol fun
fun in section .rodata of libBar.so
```

It's a bit crazy that it tries to call variable as a function, but that's what it tries to do.

The question is, how do I disambiguate the symbol and instruct gdb to use one from `libFoo` ?

So far, the only way I found requires a manual step (`info function ^fun$` above) and then `call (void)0x00007ffff6d7e3b0()`. This isn't too good because it doesn't allow me to script the call across different program runs.

Comment: There may be a better solution, but you could try this: `call ((void(*)())0x00007ffff6d7e3b0)()`

Comment: `call ((void(*)())0x00007ffff6d7e3b0)()` is not better than `(void)0x00007ffff6d7e3b0()`. Both work, but in both cases, the address is specific to program run and can't be used in a script designed to work in any run.

But you probably wanted to say `call ((void(*)())fun)()` ? Unfortunately this also tries to call wrong symbol.